# Matrix not being read correctly

Tags: c, matrix

Okay so my assignment is to create a program which reads an unknown matrix from a file and then calculates it's determinant in a certain way. I'm pretty much done except the numbers seem to be jumbling up after getting them from the file.

It's probably easier if you just look at my code, this is the portion up until just after reading the matrix, the values as I said are all jumbled up

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
FILE       *input;
int     i, j, temp; 
int        dim=0;
double     det;
const char inp_fn[]="matrix.dat";

/*Open File*/
input = fopen(inp_fn, "r");

/*Find the number of lines and hence dimensions*/
while (EOF != (temp = fgetc(input)))
{
    if (temp=='\n')
    {
        ++dim;
    }
}

/*Reset pointer to beginning of file and float the matrix*/
fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);
float      matrix[dim][dim];

/*Check file isn't NULL, if good fill the matrix with the values from the file*/
if( (input != (FILE*) NULL) )
{
    for(i=0; i<=dim; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=dim; j++)
        {
            fscanf(input, "%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
}
else
{
    printf("Could not open file!\n");
}
```

So yer if you guys can see anything please tell me, I'm really new to this so i'm probably missing something obvious, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for(i=0; i<=dim; i++) 
    {
        for(j=0; j<=dim; j++)
        {
            fscanf(input, "%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

it must be `i < dim` and `j < dim`.

the index of an array begin with 0, not 1.